# spark streaming writestream issue

Tags: json, schema, spark-streaming

I am trying to make a dynamic schema creation out of JSON records from text file as **every record will have different schema**. The following is my code.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{IntegerType, StringType, StructField, StructType}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{lit, schema_of_json, from_json, col}

object streamingexample {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark:SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
      .master("local[*]")
      .appName("SparkByExamples")
      .getOrCreate()
    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
    import spark.implicits._
    val df1 = spark.readStream.textFile("C:\\Users\\sheol\\Desktop\\streaming")
    val newdf11=df1
    val json_schema = newdf11.select("value").collect().map(x => x.get(0)).mkString(",")
    val df2 = df1.select(from_json($"value", schema_of_json(json_schema)).alias("value_new"))
    val df3 = df2.select($"value_new.*")
    df3.printSchema()
    df3.writeStream
      .option("truncate", "false")
      .format("console")
      .start()
      .awaitTermination()
     }
}
```

I am getting the following error. Please help on how to fix the code. I tried a lot. unable to figure out.

```
Error: Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();;
```

Sample data:

```
{"name":"Michael"}
{"name":"Andy", "age":30}
{"name":"Justin", "age":19}
```

Answer (score 0):

This exception occurred because you are trying to access the data from the stream before the stream was started. Issues is with the **df3.printSchema()** make sure to call this function after the stream start.

Comment: val json_schema = newdf11.select("value").collect().map(x => x.get(0)).mkString(",")      this is the line the code shows error from..

Comment: I hope your issue resolved. We are not allowed to access data before the stream start.

Comment: I understand it now. However any better way to look at this? I may need a structtype or string of the incoming JSON data to use here for updating the schema everytime..

Comment: In my previous project I have done like this to convert into struct type.                   val staticInputDS = spark.readStream.option("header", "true").schema(Util.schema).csv("hdfs://master:9000/user/hadoop/test*.csv")

Answer (score 0):

This statement in your code causing the problem from your code, as you already know.

```
val json_schema = newdf11.select("value").collect().map(x => x.get(0)).mkString(",")
```

---

You can get json schema in a different way like below...

```
val dd: DataFrame =    spark.read.json("C:\\Users\\sheol\\Desktop\\streaming")
      dd.show()
/** you can use  val df1 = spark.readStream.textFile(yourfile) also **/

      val json_schema = dd.schema.json;
      println(json_schema)
```

Result :

```
+----+-------+
| age|   name|
+----+-------+
|null|Michael|
|  30|   Andy|
|  19| Justin|
+----+-------+

{"type":"struct","fields":[{"name":"age","type":"long","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"name","type":"string","nullable":true,"metadata":{}}]}
```

*you can further refine to your requirements I will leave it to you*